# NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException being thrown incorrectly

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate

I have this somewhat huge query which is returning the correct result when I run it  on SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, 'ANALYSIS' AS type, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM Analysis a WHERE a.category_neoId IS NULL 

UNION 

SELECT bp.neoId, bp.name, 'BUSINESS_PERFORMANCE' AS type, sc.defaultPermission, sp.flags, sp.securityEntity_neoId FROM BPQuery bp LEFT JOIN SecurityController sc ON bp.userSecurityController_neoId = sc.neoId LEFT JOIN SecurityPermission sp ON bp.userSecurityController_neoId = sp.controller_neoId WHERE bp.category_neoId IS NULL 

UNION 

SELECT bpc.neoId, bpc.name, 'BUSINESS_PERFORMANCE_CONSOLIDATED' AS type, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM BPConsolidatedQuery bpc WHERE bpc.category_neoId IS NULL 

UNION 

SELECT ip.neoId, ip.name, 'INDICATORS_PANEL' AS type, sc.defaultPermission, sp.flags, sp.securityEntity_neoId FROM NeoDashBoard ip LEFT JOIN SecurityController sc ON ip.userSecurityController_neoId = sc.neoId LEFT JOIN SecurityPermission sp ON ip.userSecurityController_neoId = sp.controller_neoId WHERE ip.category_neoId IS NULL 

UNION 

SELECT r.neoId, r.name, 'REPORT' AS type, sc.defaultPermission, sp.flags, sp.securityEntity_neoId FROM NeoReport r LEFT JOIN SecurityController sc ON r.userSecurityController_neoId = sc.neoId LEFT JOIN SecurityPermission sp ON r.userSecurityController_neoId = sp.controller_neoId WHERE r.category_neoId IS NULL
```

However, when I run it on `entityManager.createNativeQuery(thisHugeQuery).getResultList()`, it throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.loader.custom.NonUniqueDiscoveredSqlAliasException: Encountered a duplicated sql alias [] during auto-discovery of a native-sql query
```

I really couldn't find any real query duplicates on it. The SecurityPermission and SecurityController are the only duplicate aliases (`sc` and `sp`), but as far as I know, since I am not selecting from it, only joining and referencing the same tables, it shouldn't be a problem for Hibernate to correctly identify it.

Comment: In the first select you have three times `NULL, NULL, NULL` and no alias. You should give them one. (each of them a different alias of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't have column names for the last 3 columns. Provide a column alias for each of those three columns and this should work.

BTW, you might consider using UNION ALL unless you are trying to return only distinct rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give the first query last three columns `NULL` alias name. otherwise those columns are no name.

```
SELECT a.id, 
       a.NAME, 
       'ANALYSIS' AS type, 
       NULL as 'defaultpermission', 
       NULL as 'flags', 
       NULL as 'securityentity_neoid'
FROM   analysis a 
WHERE  a.category_neoid IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT bp.neoid, 
       bp.NAME, 
       'BUSINESS_PERFORMANCE' AS type, 
       sc.defaultpermission, 
       sp.flags, 
       sp.securityentity_neoid 
FROM   bpquery bp 
       LEFT JOIN securitycontroller sc 
              ON bp.usersecuritycontroller_neoid = sc.neoid 
       LEFT JOIN securitypermission sp 
              ON bp.usersecuritycontroller_neoid = sp.controller_neoid 
WHERE  bp.category_neoid IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT bpc.neoid, 
       bpc.NAME, 
       'BUSINESS_PERFORMANCE_CONSOLIDATED' AS type, 
       NULL, 
       NULL, 
       NULL 
FROM   bpconsolidatedquery bpc 
WHERE  bpc.category_neoid IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT ip.neoid, 
       ip.NAME, 
       'INDICATORS_PANEL' AS type, 
       sc.defaultpermission, 
       sp.flags, 
       sp.securityentity_neoid 
FROM   neodashboard ip 
       LEFT JOIN securitycontroller sc 
              ON ip.usersecuritycontroller_neoid = sc.neoid 
       LEFT JOIN securitypermission sp 
              ON ip.usersecuritycontroller_neoid = sp.controller_neoid 
WHERE  ip.category_neoid IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT r.neoid, 
       r.NAME, 
       'REPORT' AS type, 
       sc.defaultpermission, 
       sp.flags, 
       sp.securityentity_neoid 
FROM   neoreport r 
       LEFT JOIN securitycontroller sc 
              ON r.usersecuritycontroller_neoid = sc.neoid 
       LEFT JOIN securitypermission sp 
              ON r.usersecuritycontroller_neoid = sp.controller_neoid 
WHERE  r.category_neoid IS NULL
```